# Join 4 tables through SQL with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Four tables like below, need to be joined to form one table.

Merchants Table

```
Date|Merchants|Date ID
```

Users Table

```
Date|Users|Date ID
```

Sales Table

```
Date|Sales|Date ID
```

Revenue Table

```
Date|Revenue|Date ID
```

**Date** and **Date ID** are pretty much the same. All these tables get the corresponding value for each day. But on a day, when there are new merchants, there need not be new users. On a day, when there is Sales and Revenue, there need not be new merchants.

But, when I try to use the usual SELECT query, with three LEFT JOINs, I do not get all the data.

How to include all dates from all four tables and have **0** when there is no data, for Sales, Users, etc.,?

It seems pretty much achievable but I'm not able to. :-/

Comment: Please include your query which you have tried, and some sample data might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could LEFT JOIN them to a sub-query with all the Date ID.

```
SELECT 
s.Sales, 
m.Merchants, 
u.Users, 
r.Revenue,
f.`Date ID`
FROM 
(
  SELECT `Date ID` FROM Sales UNION
  SELECT `Date ID` FROM Merchants UNION
  SELECT `Date ID` FROM Users UNION
  SELECT `Date ID` FROM Revenue
) f
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON s.`Date ID` = f.`Date ID`
LEFT JOIN Merchants m ON m.`Date ID` = f.`Date ID`
LEFT JOIN Users u ON u.`Date ID` = f.`Date ID`
LEFT JOIN Revenue r ON r.`Date ID` = f.`Date ID`
```

Comment: it works. Thanks. But, how does the Date ID field, be cast as Date datatype?

Comment: @Shyam I don't know what kind of data is in that field. But you could also just simply add one of the Date fields to the select? Or add it to the unioned selects?

Comment: @Shyam Actually, since it could be that some of the left joined tables won't have a match, you could use a COALESCE. It takes the first that isn't NULL.  I.e.  `SELECT COALESCE(s.Date,m.Date,u.Date,r.Date) AS Date, ...`

Comment: @Shyam And another way, assuming all Date correspond with the same Date ID, is to replace all the Date ID in the current query with Date. Also assuming that it's a DATE type, and not a DATETIME type that can have different hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: that Date ID is a Date field in the format YYYY-MM-DD. It doesn't have time. So, it is assured that it's a DATE type, and not a DATETIME type.

Comment: @Shyam If `Date ID` already a DATE then you don't have to cast it to a DATE.  If you need it to be displayed in another format? Then you could for example use the [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) function to display it in your desired format.

Comment: Thanks LukStorms. Maybe, I wasn't more clear in my request. I had to use STR_TO_DATE function, for my requirement. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @Shyam Oh I see, so it was a varchar. Indeed, that [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function does the opposite of DATE_FORMAT.  But if it's in the "YYYY-MM-DD" format, then you could also use [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp) for that. Because YYYY-MM-DD is standard format that's never misunderstood as YYYY-DD-MM.

Comment: LukStorms, in your answer, where you suggested 4 LEFT JOINs, there is a possibility that there would be a lot of null values. Is there a chance that all these NULL values, be replaced by 0 (Zero)?

Comment: @Shyam Yes, IFNULL or the SQL standard COALESCE. Reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).

Comment: LukStorms, you saved my day! Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you try below way

```
select t.*,m.Merchants,r.Revenue from
       (
        select u.dateID,s.Sales,u.Users form Users u inner join  Sales s on  
        u.dateID=s.dateID
      ) as t left join Merchants m ON t.dateid= m.Dateid
             left join Revenue r on t.dateid=r.dateid
```